# How to programatically add CanvasOverlay objects in jqPlot?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am trying to add canvasOverlay objects dynamically in jqPlot. I followed this link. [horizontalLine and verticalLine in JQPlot dynamically by canvasOverlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005631/horizontalline-and-verticalline-in-jqplot-dynamically-by-canvasoverlay/13005948#13005948)

I have the a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/HbU85/  for the above solution. Somehow the vertical line does not get rendered.

### Works:

```
canvasOverlay: {
                    show: true,
                    objects: [{line:{start:[new Date('2012-05-01').getTime(),0],stop :[new Date('2012-05-10').getTime(),0],
                   lineWidth: 1000,color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0,0.45)',shadow: false,lineCap : 'butt'}}]
                },
```

### Does not work:

```
    var myArray = Array();
    myArray.push({line:{start:[new Date('2012-05-01').getTime(),0],stop :[new Date('2012-05-10').getTime(),0],
                   lineWidth: 1000,color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0,0.45)',shadow: false,lineCap : 'butt'}});
.
.
.
.
                canvasOverlay: {
                    show: true,
                    objects: [myArray]
                },
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Almost right.

As you are already defining an array `var myArray = Array();`, you do not redefined another one in `canvasOverlay` with `objects: [myArray]`.

Just use `objects: myArray` instead : http://jsfiddle.net/HbU85/1/